# How to delete android cache for all apps installed in android

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development and I want to how I can show list of all installed apps in android phone and delete their cache files by pressing button.

What is the most effective way across?

Thanks

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507092/android-clear-cache-of-all-apps

Comment: @Wikki have u found anything ?