# How to remove all applications from android cache programmatically?

Tags: android

Please I need some help with this.
What I want is to remove all apps from cache when, for example, press a button.
Let's say that I have opened Whatsapp, Gmail , Fb and my Custom App. When pressed a button from my custom app, I want to clean all the apps that I opened before (Whatsapp, Gmail, Fb).
Is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: I also had the same problem "Helped me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14509140/4406647) " check

Comment: I did the same. But it doesn't work for me. How did you do it? Please help me!